# python "No module named" error when calling a submodule

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having trouble with the import statement as Python reports that there is no module named the_page or the_generator.

task_a.py contains `import generator.the_page as ThePage`, and when run as the main script, causes no problem.

the_generator.py contains `import tasks.task_a`, but when i run it as the main script, python throws the following error..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/generator/the_generator.py", line 7, in <module>
    import tasks.tasks_a
  File "/generator/tasks/tasks_a.py", line 3, in <module>
    import generator.the_page as ThePage
ImportError: No module named the_page
```

Here's the structure.

```
generator/
    __init__.py
    the_generator.py
    the_page.py
    tasks/
        __init__.py
        task_a.py
```

Maybe you can help with my problem guys. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You should not try to run scripts from the middle of a package as top-level scripts. The FAQ explains why, but basically, the main problem is exactly this: you confuse imports to the rest of the package. (There's also the fact that you can end up with the same module being imported twice, because Python can't tell that the two different names refer to the same module.)

Answer (score 10):

Running scripts from the middle of a package is a bad idea, for a number of reasons, the most obvious of which is the one you're running into: When you `import generator.the_generator` somewhere, `generator` ends up as a package, so an absolute import of `generator.the_page`, or a relative import, will work fine. But when you just run the script `generator/the_generator.py`, there is no `generator.the_generator`, just `__main__`, and there is no `generator` package. The only other way Python could know how to find `generator.the_page` would be if the parent directory of `generator` were on `sys.path`, which it isn't.

As you can guess, you *can* work around this by munging `sys.path` to put the appropriate parent directory on there… but this is a bad idea too.

There are also many other problems with this solution. Most seriously, it can very easily lead to the same module being imported twice (because Python has no way of knowing that two apparently-unrelated names happen to refer to the same module). It's also hard to deploy (you can't install a script to `/usr/local/bin` if it depends on being inside a package…), it won't work if your package is run out of a .zip or .egg, etc.

---

There are two standard ways to solve this.

First, just run the script as a module rather than as a script. From the parent directory of `generator`, just `python -m generator.the_generator` instead of `python generator/the_generator.py`.

A major advantage of this is that it works just as well in normal installed deployments, when `generator` is in site-packages somewhere, as in testing.

Alternatively, create a script that sits alongside `generator`, and run that, not a module inside of it. This can be as trivial as moving all the `if __name__ == '__main__':` code in `the_generator.py` into a function, then writing two-line wrapper:

```
import generator.the_generator
generator.the_generator.main()
```

Again, this works just as well in normal installed deployments. Plus, it means the script can get installed into your `bin` directory, making things even easier, just like `pip` or `ipython`.

Comment: I think they fixed a lot of this with [PEP 366](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/), though you have to set `__package__` explicitly.

Comment: @user2357112: No, it really doesn't. If the top-level package is already absolute-importable, setting `__package__` will _also_ make relative imports work. (When PEP 366 was being discussed, it was explicitly decided not to do anything to make it easier to munge the path to fake up absolute imports, because that's usually a bad idea, and whatever you need to do should be explicitly and obviously a hack.)

Comment: Running the script as a module works like a charm! `python -m generator.the_generator`